# Mailchimp with django

Tags: django, mailchimp

I used the django-mailchmip for newsletter creation.
I properly integrate the mailchimp with django, I subscribe user also creates the campaign using template_id, But i want to add the content in the template dynamically in django.
Template structure will be predefined, i just want to add the proper data into proper place in the template with django.

Can please anybody help me, how it should be done?

Thanks

Comment: I properly call the connection() method i want to call the campaign_create() method in that method i have to pass the template id along with the dynamic content in that template. Means template structure will be fixed but the content will be added dynamically using django-mailchimp.

Comment: Above issue gets resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is because of Repeatable section. Repeatable section having different way to add data.

```
template_content = {'html_repeat_1:0:postcard_heading00':postcard_heading_data,
                  'html_repeat_1:0:postcard_image': postcard_img_data, 
                  'html_repeat_1:0:std_content00': std_content_data}
```

Means ['repatable_section']:['index']:['section_name']

I done this way and problem gets solved.

Answer (score 0):

I was not using djano-mailchimp, but I've managed to do the same with the plain Mailchimp API using mailsnake and it just wasn't complicated.

You can easily pass those in something like:

```
 cid = mailsnake.campaignCreate(type='regular',
                                options={
                                             'list_id': list_id,
                                             'subject': some_subject,
                                             'template_id': some_template_id,
                                        },
                                segment_opts=segment,
                                content={
                                             'html_HEADER': some_header,
                                             'html_MAIN': some_main_content,

                                        }
                                )
```

Comment: Yes. I write the same code, but these sections for template not working. When i retrieve all the templates then it displays the sections like std_preheader_content, postcard_heading00, std_content00, std_footer, etc

Comment: I use these sections then it will work for the simple template where nothing will be set. But this content will not be added into the template where header image is set.
Can you suggest me how he should be done?

Comment: The data will be added into the sections like "std_preheader_content", "std_preheader_links,"std_social",and "std_footer". Anything will be added into the above section image or text thats added properly.

Problem with the sections like "postcard_heading00", "std_content00" and "postcard_image" section.
Is there any problem with the repeatable section?